# How to get methods from vendor classes

Tags: 8

I use get_class_methods to get classes for Drupal classes, for example I go to devel/php and run:

```
$coupon = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('commerce_promotion_coupon')->load(3);

ksm(get_class_methods($coupon));`
```

But If I want to get list of classes for some vendor library I don't know how to get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's off-topic. But try this:

```
$ composer require ramsey/uuid
```

And then put the whole use statement without `use` into [`get_class_methods()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-class-methods.php):

```
ksm(get_class_methods('Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid'));
```

---

Putting that into a [`new ReflectionClass()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) would actually give you much more useful output:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid');
$methods = $class->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
ksm($methods);
```